# dictionary sort value by type

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

Problem Statement: I have a dictioary where values are many different type like int, str, list, class, class atrribute, class method etc. I want to do value sorting by `type`. Like string, list, would be first and then rest.,

Can someone suggest how to write a key function so that I can control `sorting by type`

```
class dummy:
    a = 1

obj = dummy()
x = {'b':1,'a':'abc','c':obj, 'd':obj.a, 'e': [1,2,3]}
x = dict(sorted(x.items() , key = lambda x:type(x[1]))) #It will fail as can't compare the type
print(x)
```

Expcted output:

> print(x)

`{'a':'abc','e': [1,2,3] ,'c':obj, 'd':obj.a, 'b':1}`

Comment: If you really want to do this, use a dictionary mapping types to numeric values. But really, sorting dictionaries isn't really meaningful because the whole point of dictionaries is to be able to lookup values by a key instead of an ordered index. Sorting a dictionary is usually meaningless.

Comment: Thanks. It is for a very special need in my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the key to the `sorted` function, I suggest this function:

```py
lambda x: (not isinstance(x[1], str), not isinstance(x[1], list), type(x[1]).__name__)
```

This will map values as follows:

- strings to the tuple `(False, True, 'str')`;
- lists to the tuple `(True, False, 'list')`;
- other objects to a tuple `(True, True, 'something else')`.

Since tuples are sorted in lexicographical order, and `False < True`, this will put strings first, lists second, and values of other types will be sorted in alphabetical order of the name of the type.

With the example data provided in your question:

```py
class dummy:
    a = 1

obj = dummy()
d = {'b':1,'a':'abc','c':obj, 'd':obj.a, 'e': [1,2,3]}
d = dict(sorted(d.items() , key = lambda x: (not isinstance(x[1], str), not isinstance(x[1], list), type(x[1]).__name__))) 

print(d)

{'a': 'abc',                                  # (False, True, 'str')
 'e': [1, 2, 3],                              # (True, False, 'list')
 'c': <__main__.dummy object at 0x10f311ba8>, # (True, True, 'dummy')
 'b': 1,                                      # (True, True, 'int')
 'd': 1                                       # (True, True, 'int')
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is probably a better way to do this, but this example works:

```
>>> maps = {
    'str': 0,
    'list': 1,
    'int': 2,
    'dummy': 3
}

>>> dict(sorted(x.items(), key=lambda x: maps.get(type(x[1]).__name__, 999)))
{'a': 'abc', 'e': [1, 2, 3], 'b': 1, 'd': 1, 'c': <__main__.dummy object at 0x000001C1FEB8B250>}
```

alternative (the same, but `lambda` is replaced with a full fledged function):

```
>>> maps = {
    'str': 0,
    'list': 1,
    'int': 2,
    'dummy': 3
}

>>> def sort_key(x):
    value = x[1]
    map_key =  type(value).__name__
    return maps.get(map_key, 999)

>>> dict(sorted(x.items(), key=sort_key))
{'a': 'abc', 'e': [1, 2, 3], 'b': 1, 'd': 1, 'c': <__main__.dummy object at 0x000001BE86F8BB50>}
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason not to simply use `{str: 0, ..., dummy: 3}` and not bother with calling `__name__`?

Comment: I was thinking of doing that at first. I actually did it, and it worked. But it feels very wrong, so I changed it to use string representations instead

Comment: Eh, everything's an object in Python. Classes and built-in functions are hashable.

Comment: Only thing I'd say is maybe consider converting the sort key to a named function for the sake of cleanliness. Otherwise +1.

Comment: that's a good point, I'll include it as an alternative

Comment: I suggest using `maps.get(type(x[1]).__name__, 999)` instead of `maps[type(x[1]).__name__]`, to avoid crashing if the type name is not in the dictionary.

Comment: added already now

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use str convertion:

```
class dummy:
    a = 1

obj = dummy()
x = {'b':1,'a':'abc','c':obj, 'd':obj.a, 'e': [1,2,3]}
x = dict(sorted(x.items() , key = lambda x:str(type(x[1])))) #It will fail as can't compare the type
print(x)
```

Comment: this won't produce the desired outcome, since `'list' < 'str'`

Comment: You have third parameter in sorted reverse = True, or many other methods like slices